# Error AUTH LOGIN failed when send email via yahoo

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, sendmail

I have a source code to send email via yahoo or gmail and i want to use smtp or pop3. I'm try to do with yahoo mail. This is my source code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SendMail a = new SendMail();
    a.postMail();
}

public void postMail() {
    MimeMessage message = null;  

    try {
        Properties mailProp = new Properties();
        mailProp.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.bizmail.yahoo.com");
        mailProp.put("mail.smtp.port","465");                 
        mailProp.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");
        mailProp.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");           
        mailProp.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback","false");
        mailProp.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");//true: ssl, false : non ssl
        mailProp.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        mailProp.put("mail.pop3.host", "pop.bizmail.yahoo.com");
        mailProp.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");

        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            //override the getPasswordAuthentication method
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("myemail", "mypassword");
            }
        };

        Session session = Session.getInstance(mailProp, auth); 

        session.setDebug(true);
        message = new MimeMessage(session);  

        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("emailid@yahoo.com"));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, 
                new InternetAddress("emailreceipt@yahoo.com"));
        message.setSubject("Hello JavaMail");
        message.setText("Welcome to Yahoo's JavaMail");

        // Send message
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Message Sent");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but when i run it it has error like that :

```
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN failed
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 530 Access denied
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:914)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:825)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:730)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:267)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:252)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:174)
at SendMail.postMail(SendMail.java:57)
at SendMail.main(SendMail.java:19)\
```

Can somebody help me ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you trying to authenticate with a regular Yahoo! mail account, or a Business Mail account? And are you using your full email address in place of "myemail", or just the username portion?

Comment: Yes, i'm using regular yahoo mail account. i try business mail account but i not working.

Comment: Your code has several [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  Correct them, update your post with the new code, and post the [debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) if it still fails.  See also the [JavaMail FAQ entry about Yahoo Mail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#yahoomail); try using the [smtpsend sample program](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples) to make sure your username and password are working.

Comment: If this is not a Y! Business account then you're using the incorrect SMTP server, you should be using `smtp.mail.yahoo.com` (https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN4724.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but, yahoos smtp port is 587 or 25 I think and gmails port is 465. Also i assume you are using your email and not placeholders. Also try removing the @yahoo.com

Comment: Yes, but i try to change port to 587and it not working.

Comment: Does it give you the same error or a different one?

Comment: Thank you, i fixed it. Because my eclipse don't clear session so when i build it, it still run old source code.

Answer (score 0):

try enabled less secure sign in application on your yahoo email account, just like at gmail.